# Gravity Forms advance now causing page load

Tags: wordpress, reload, gravityforms

I have "inherited" a WordPress site which uses the Gravity Form plugin. It was working such that advancing to the next field did not cause the page to load (with the next field). Instead it displayed the "spinner" icon.

I don't know what has changed but now advancing to the next field causes the page to reload (i.e no spinner). The form is advancing correctly in all other respects.

I cannot find any setting that determines this behaviour, nor has a search of the internet shed any extra light on this matter. Help!?

Comment: Hi Askelkana, Can you please export the form so I can take a look at it? Also, it would be very helpful if you can show me the site that is working correctly, and the site that has the issue.

Comment: Site is: https://national-debtadvice.co.uk/  

Export is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/t5hkea2we1cb456/gravityforms-export-2021-05-11.json?dl=0

Comment: sounds like the form is not using AJAX, check that this option is switched on